# installed project on local and have an error

Tags: magento2, setup, websites

I installed project on local , used dump in the database but I have an error

```
{"0":"The website with code base that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver\\Website->getDefaultStoreId() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/DefaultStore.php:70]\n#2 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\DefaultStore->beforeDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:121]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:40]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/admin","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Tried :
dockergento composer dump-autoload

docker exec -it -u 0 hp_redis_1 bash

redis-cli flushall.
cleared cache and removed generated code but no success.

still an error .

Comment: Change url path in `core_config_data` table.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh have done it.

Comment: Check that domain name is hosted or not.